# Oracle: JSON object members inside CASE expression?

Tags: json, oracle

I'm trying to assemble a JSON document with mixed types like `[["array"],{"data":"object"},"string"]` from a conditional expression.

If I put only JSON types inside, Oracle somehow surmises that I'm composing them inside the outer document:

```
with t as (
    select 'array'  data from dual union ALL
    select 'object'      from dual union all
    select 'string'      from dual
)
select json_arrayagg(
  case data
    when 'array'  then json_array(data)
    when 'object' then json_object('key' value data)
  end json
)
from t
/

JSON
------------------------------------------------
[["array"],{"data":"object"}]
```

As soon as I add a string to the mix, the results of the `CASE` expression are all treated as strings and encoded accordingly:

```
with t as (
    select 'array'  data from dual union ALL
    select 'object'      from dual union all
    select 'string'      from dual
)
select json_arrayagg(
  case data
    when 'array'  then json_array(data)
    when 'object' then json_object('key' value data)
    else data
  end
)
from t
/

JSON
------------------------------------------------
["[\"array\"]","{\"data\":\"object\"}","string"]
```

But if I tell `json_arrayagg` to treat it as JSON, the last string member is *not* handled, resulting in an invalid document:

```
with t as (
    select 'array'  data from dual union ALL
    select 'object'      from dual union all
    select 'string'      from dual
)
select json_arrayagg(
  case data
    when 'array'  then json_array(data)
    when 'object' then json_object('data' value data)
    else data
  end FORMAT JSON
) json
from t

JSON
------------------------------------------------
[["array"],{"data":"object"},string]
```

I can't find any function like `json_string` to JSONify `varchar2`, and I'd prefer not to do it by hand.

```
SQL> select banner_full from v$version ;

BANNER_FULL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.13.0.0.0
```

Comment: Can you add the result you want?

Comment: If you mean the desired output from the example, it's in the first line.

Comment: Rather than `json_string`, we should ask for an overloaded `json_scalar` function, which creates a JSON scalar of either string, number, or `true/false/null` data type (obviously the latter won't be possible directly, as Oracle SQL does not support the Boolean data type).

Comment: One workaround (which you would rather avoid, but you may not have a choice) - wrap the desired scalar within `json_array` and then ditch the surrounding brackets. This will wrap the string within double-quotes, it will escape double-quotes and backslashes within the string, etc. If you need this often, create your own `json_scalar` function and use it whenever it's needed.

Comment: Yes, `json_scalar` is what I had in mind. Another possibility would be per-member `format json` clauses. The substr hack isn't that bad – thanks!

Comment: For simple cases like this, you can use '"'||data||'"' to get the result. And json_scalar is in 21c, not backported to 19c (yet)

Comment: @gsalem, thanks for the info on 21c (Oracle's sure dragged their feet with JSON). I'm trying not to assume anything about my data, so I'll probably use `regexp_substr(json_array(data), '".*"')` (`*` is greedy). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a9683c0253f2d2ffd6b11e4b52f7b839